# Django: sorl-thumbnail in a for template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, sorl-thumbnail

First of all, a django newbie, so take it easy ;)

I'm trying to do some thumbnails within a for loop - the next thing will be Pagination, or group_by, but one problem at a time ;)

The thing is I've this:

```
 {% for item in object_list %}
  <li>{{ item.name }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
```

And also managed to work the sorl-thumbnail in views.py / item template using this: (only works for a single item)

```
def get_item(request, item_slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug_name=item_slug)
    # get() returned more than one
    # img = item.images.get() 
    imgs = item.images.filter(is_poster=True)
    img_src = imgs[0].src if imgs else None

    return render_to_response('items/get_item.html', {
        'item': item,
        'title': item.name,
        'image': img_src,
    })
```

So I'm stucked in the for/sorl-thumbnail part. I got this but it isn't working when get() returns more than one result:

```
{% for item in all_items %}
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
    {% if item.images.get %} 
      {{item.images.get }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but your problem is, but if you have a list of images you can also index the first in the template:

```
{% load thumbail %}
{% if item.images.all %}
    <img src="{% thumbnail item.images.all.0 100x100 %}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: yeah, that fixed it though I must look how to do the item.images.filter(is_poster=True) in template but for the moment that was good man, except that should be item.images.all.0.src

Comment: You could make a custom manager (http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_managers/) method for your images, eg. `is_poster` that you could also call then from your template (`{{ item.images.is_poster }}`).